# How do I change text color using flash actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript, text, colors

How do I change text color using flash actionscript 2?

Comment: Is this a question that answers itself?

Comment: I love that a question with -3 gets over 1k views

Answer (score 10, accepted):

myTextField.textColor = 0x634634

Answer (score 2):

myTextField.textColor = 0x634634

That works and it's the easiest, why bother with the extra nonsense?